# Trying to wrap angular directive in another directive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to wrap a directive in another directive, and am having an issue. For example, using the UI Bootstrap tabs and pane directive:

I want to turn something like:

```
<tabs>
    <pane heading="FOO">...</pane>
    <pane heading="BAR">...</pane>
</tabs>
```

in to:

```
<tabs>
    <pane-wrapper heading="FOO">...</pane-wrapper>
    <pane-wrapper heading="BAR">...</pane-wrapper>
</tabs>
```

where pane-wrapper directive looks like:

```
angular.module('test').directive('paneWrapper', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: "<pane ng-transclude></pane>" //somehow need to pass along the heading attribute
        }
    });
```

The reason I want to do this is because, I don't want to heavily modify pane, I want to wrap it and perhaps have multiple directives in one etc. I suppose I could completely copy the pane directive and change it as one option.

Anyway, I get the error:

```
Error: Multiple directives [ngTransclude, ngTransclude] asking for 'ngTransclude' controller on <div class='tab-pane' ng-class='active: selected' ng-show='selected' ng-tranclude=''>
```

Thoughts?

I shouldn't need to create a pane-wrapper scope right? There is a parent scope with various data... I just want to wrap this and create a reusable component.

Comment: This code, if it worked, wouldn't *do* anything. Can you provide a little more detail on your use case? What do you want to do with a pane that you can't do already?

Comment: There have been a few instances of when I've wanted to do something like this. If I want to wrap several directives together, to provide a reusable directive/component with others. In this case I am using the tabs directive and the carousel directive for paging/navigation, and I want the top level directive to have the <carousel> in it's directive, so you can simply add slides underneath.

Comment: But why can't, for example, the carousel be a child element of the pane? Why do they need to be the same element? In this case, it can't even work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
iElement.html($compile(<pane..)(scope));
```

remove the template property and rely on compiling the `<pane>` and updating iElement html directly.

You might want to use `replace: true` property in the wrapper directive.