# Can I wrap an AngularJS directive around another directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I do something like this?

```
<scrollable-directive>
    <fun-content-directive>
    </fun-content-directive>
</scrollable-directive>
```

e.g I want to build out a custom scrolling container with events for infinite scrolling, etc. that I can put content in.

Similar to this question: 
[Trying to wrap angular directive in another directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662237/trying-to-wrap-angular-directive-in-another-directive)

Comment: Look at the transclude option for the outer directive. Or include the inner directive in the template of the outer one.

Comment: Yeah Hawk I don't grasp what the problem is really.  As @aet says this can be done without any real issue, what problem are you encountering?

Comment: Directives can depend on parent directives and also share the controller, using the `require` attribute, but unsure exactly what you want to achieve. There's nothing stopping you from putting directives inside each other, just so long as you use the `transclude` option as aet mentioned.

Comment: Yep, wasn't clear on the transclude option. This article helped me understand it: http://blog.omkarpatil.com/2012/11/transclude-in-angularjs.html Thanks for pointing me back in the right direction.